# Algorithm for constructing primes

Tags: elementary-number-theory, algorithms, prime-numbers

Are there any good algorithms which can be used to construct a prime greater than $n$, for arbitrary $n$?

There are some brute force approaches: for example, factoring $n!+1$. However, I'm looking for something significantly more efficient; preferably, polynomial in $n$.

Also, if anyone knows of a proof showing a bound on the speed of such an algorithm (say, $n^4$), I would like to hear about it.

EDIT: It appears that polynomial in $\ln(n)$ makes more sense.

Comment: If $n$ is odd, keep incrementing by 2 for as long as a test for compositeness returns true. If $n$ is even, add 1 first before using the procedure for odd $n$.

Comment: Will any prime do? Or are you looking for the least such prime? In any case, see this previous question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8865/the-least-prime-greater-than-2000

Comment: I am unsure whether to close this as a dupe, there could be faster algorithms if _any_ prime is sought. (For instance if we knew an upper bound for $n$, we could just hardcode it).

Comment: Trial division requires sqrt(n) queries "does m divide n?" (which can be tested in O(log n) time by Euclid's algorithm).  There is always a prime between n+1 and 2(n+1).  Hence, we can always find a prime greater than n in O(n*sqrt(n)*log n) time using J.M.'s algorithm.  [you're probably after polynomial in log n]

Comment: I think you mean factoring n! + 1.

Comment: The answer depends largely on n. For example, if n = 10^6 we can use a simple algorithm, but for n = 10^400 we would generally want something more advanced. The largest known prime according to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Largest_known_prime_number) is 2^43112609 − 1. So obviously letting n = 2^43112609 − 1 will cause some problems.

Comment: I have an algorithm that runs in poly time, but requires that $n$ is given in unary (smirk!).

Comment: Did you mean a prime number larger than $2^{n}$ or something equivalent or like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Terence Tao has set up a "polymath project" which addresses exactly your question. Here is the relevant page:

http://michaelnielsen.org/polymath1/index.php?title=Finding_primes

It contains a list of conjectures, partial results and references. To sum it all up: At the moment the answer to your question is No.

Answer (score 6):

Well theoretically speaking, there is a *deterministic* $\mathcal{O}(n \log ^{12} n)$ time algorithm.

By Bertrand's postulate, there is a prime $p$ guaranteed to satisfy $n \le p \lt2n$. (In practice, you should hit one much earlier than $2n$, owing to the prime number theorem).

Use the AKS primality testing program to test each of the numbers in the range $[n, 2n)$ and you will find one.

You can also try some sieving etc as suggested in the answers to this other question here: [The least prime greater than 2000](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8865/the-least-prime-greater-than-2000)

Comment: It's been a while since I last looked into this subject (which was the time AKS was first published XD ): is AKS practical nowadays?

Comment: @J.M: I believe they got it down to $\log^6 n$, but I have heard it is still impractical. That is why I specifically said "theoretically speaking..." :-)

Comment: The time can be decreased to $O(n^{0.525+\varepsilon})$ due to Baker-Harman-Pintz 2001.

Answer (score 1):

There is an algorithm of complexity $O((\ln n) \cdot P(n))$ where $P(n)$ is the complexity of computing the prime counting function on n (usually denoted $\pi(n)$).

By Bertrand's postulate there is a prime in the interval $[n,2n]$ so you can do a binary search on it:

If $\pi\left(n+\frac{n}{2}\right)-\pi(n)$ > 1 there is a prime in the interval $\left[n, n+\frac{n}{2}\right]$, otherwise there is a prime in the interval $\left[n+\frac{n}{2}+1,2n\right]$ and so you obtain a smaller interval that contains a prime. Repeat the calculation on the new interval. The calculation for which of the 2 intervals to use needs time $O(P(n))$. Since each interval is half the size of the previous one the total number of calculations required is O(ln n).

Odlyzko's algorithm for $\pi(n)$ has complexity $O(n^{\frac{1}{2}})$. There is a link to a short description of it on the polymath page. So the overall complexity of this algorithm is $O((\ln n)n^{\frac{1}{2}})$.

Comment: Isn't it $O(n^{0.5+\varepsilon})$?  In that case the $\varepsilon$ subsumes the $\log n$ term entirely.

Answer (score 0):

Polynomial in $n$ is not efficient because the input length (measured in bits) is $\log_2 n$ and so $n$ is exponentially large in relation to your input length.

So it is easy to find a prime number greater than $n$ in time polynomial in $n$ (e.g. with the answer from Moron).

If you are interested in a deterministic algorithm than the polymath project gives you the current known results.

But there is a randomized algorithm with time polynomial in $\log_2 n$ that gives you a prime greater than $n$. You pick a random number from the set $n, \ldots, 2n$ and check this number with AKS or [Miller Rabin primality test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_primality_test). With the [prime number theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem) you can proof that there are enough primes in the set (for large $n$) and if you repeat this algorithm $O(\log_2 n)$ times you find a prime with high probability.

At the moment I cannot find a reference for a detailed proof for the randomized algorithm. But if you are interested I can look for it when I have more time.